# PostgreSQL v10 got an error when using insert .. on conflict .. update on partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, insert, partitioning

I have the following table in my database, the table was created using django and architect.

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.results
(
    results_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('results_results_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(45) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    value double precision NOT NULL,
    scenario_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT results_pkey PRIMARY KEY (results_id),
    CONSTRAINT results_scenario_id_name_22ad9c45_uniq UNIQUE (scenario_id, name),
    CONSTRAINT results_scenario_id_d800e53c_fk_scenario_scenario_id FOREIGN KEY (scenario_id)
        REFERENCES public.scenario (scenario_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The problem I face occurs when I run the following query

```sql
insert into 
        results ("scenario_id","name","value")
    values
        (44,'footprint_km2',1000)
    on conflict 
        ("scenario_id","name")
    do update set
        "value"= excluded.value;
```

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "results_1_500000_scenario_id_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key (scenario_id, name)=(44, footprint_km2) already exists
```

which makes no sense to me because I specified an update action when a conflict occurs.
¿Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: additionally this table is partitioned

Comment: well the solution is described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182580/postgresql-upsert-not-working-on-partitioned-table)